# Cannot include custom post item within a menu

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I'm trying to insert my custom post type within a menu of a theme. This theme actually have a custom post type called `st_tours`. So when I register my custom post type I do:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite'   => array('slug' => 'tour'),
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'show_im_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=st_tours'
);

register_post_type('tour', $args);
```

but my custom post type isn't inserted in the menu of the theme, Wordpress define a new menu called `Tour`.

What I did wrong?

eg:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```php
    'show_im_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=st_tours'
```

You made a typo, it isn't `show_im_menu`, it's `show_in_menu`